# Error:fork/exec : no such file or directory -- when run Golang code in docker

Tags: go, docker, kubernetes

first of all any help is appreciated

I want execute Gocode  in a container:

```
FROM index.tenxcloud.com/tenxcloud/centos:centos7
ADD ./ping-app /wls/applications/ping-app
RUN yum install -y gcc libxml2-devel libxslt-devel && ldconfig
RUN yum install -y openssh-server net-tools telnet
RUN /bin/cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN mkdir -p /wls/logs/ && touch /wls/logs/ping-app.log
ADD run.sh /run.sh
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

but when I try and execute in a container I get the following error:

```
[root@ping-app-3618687774-abqmo ping-app]# go run main.go 
start check_server
INFO[0000] http.startHttpServer ok, listening 0.0.0.0:8080  source="api.go:106"
INFO[0000] Index=ipdata exists=true                      source="elastic.go:164"
INFO[0000] Index=ipdata Type=entity exists=true          source="elastic.go:184"
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
fork/exec : no such file or directory
```

I can't understand why this is happening and it only happened in docker, but when I run that Gocode on the host and it is ok.

```
Environment :

Centos: 7.0.1406

Kubernetes: 1.2.0

docker: 1.10.3
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Is "Gocode" and app or a package? What is you're program doing?

Comment: sorry, it is a app write by go, and the program use a go routine  interval to obtain IP info from elasticsearch ,then put in redis, the other routine get ip from redis and do ping <ip> for it continuously

Comment: Show the Dockerfile and the `docker run` command

Comment: `FROM index.tenxcloud.com/tenxcloud/centos:centos7
ADD ./ping-app /wls/applications/ping-app 
RUN yum install -y gcc libxml2-devel libxslt-devel && ldconfig
RUN yum install -y openssh-server net-tools telnet
RUN /bin/cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN mkdir -p /wls/logs/ && touch /wls/logs/ping-app.log
ADD run.sh /run.sh
CMD ["/run.sh"]`

Comment: Thanks for any help. I use kubernetes to manage my container  and the `docker run` command is `/run.sh`

Comment: The content of run.sh is `#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /wls/logs/
cd /wls/applications/ping-app && ./ping-app >> /wls/logs/ping-app.log 2>&1
/usr/sbin/sshd -D`

Answer (score 1):

sorry I have found that I missed to copy a command to container which exec.Command need to run. Anyway,thanks for help

Comment: which command did you fail to copy?!