# How do I start a docker container in Docker-Compose from an app running in another docker container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have two apps/services that I want to run under docker-compose. (AppA and AppB)

I would like to have AppA start when I run docker-compose up, but not AppB. And after various conditions are met, I want AppA (which is a Go app in the docker container) to start up AppB's docker container.

My docker-compose.yml file defines both services, and if launch with the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

Both AppA and AppB start running. (So I believe my docker-compose.yml is correctly configured)
If I want to run only AppA (and I do want that!) I run this command:

```
docker-compose up AppA
```

And only AppA will start up. (So far all good.)

When I reach the point where I want to start AppB, I have AppA call the following from golang code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker run AppB")
```

or

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker-compose start AppB")
```

Both of these generate an error:

```
Error: fork/exec docker run AppB: no such file or directory.
```

Any ideas on how to launch a docker container from a Go app inside another docker container?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071276/errorfork-exec-no-such-file-or-directory-when-run-golang-code-in-docker?

Comment: [This](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) can probably help you.

Comment: Inside the container, you need a copy of the `docker-compose.yml` file, you need a copy of the `docker-compose` tool itself, and you need unrestricted root-equivalent administrative privileges over the whole host.  Just leaving both containers running all the time seems simpler and safer.

Comment: I actually will need multiple copies of AppB and also will have other apps. I don't think having them all running at all times will be a viable solution. I need to be able to launch apps that will run for a while, then they will quit when they are done. If it was as simple as two apps I think you'd be right.  I just simplified to help define the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't copied the AppB to container appA.

You can use this command

```
docker container cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
```

Which allows you to *Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem* [docker container cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_cp/)

In you case the command can be:

```
docker container appA:/appB appB
```

From this point, you can start thinking about how to run container B inside container A.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to run appB from my appA container. In practice I have a bunch of apps, not just appB and I'd rather have them each run from their own container. I was thinking that since I have two docker containers in my docker-compose.yml that I would be able to launch the second container when I need it.  I will look into your suggestion more, maybe I'm thinking about things wrong. (And what is with people downvoting without any comment???)

Comment: Even though running a container inside a container is doable, it's not recommended and I think it's not going to solve your problem. I guess what you're trying to do is to deploy a new container in a docker host from a container, which I don't have any experience about. However, you can try writing a script to SSH to docker host and run it from container AppA.

Comment: Yes, I want to deploy a new docker container from a container.  Thanks for you comments and suggests!